# Spec($\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

What is Spec($\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$)?

Where Spec(R) denotes the set of all prime ideals of R

Comment: $\mathrm{Spec}(R \times S) = \mathrm{Spec}(R) \sqcup \mathrm{Spec}(S)$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: If $R$ and $S$ are rings, all ideals of $R\times S$ are of the form $I\times J$ where $I$ is an ideal of $R$ and $J$ is an ideal of $S$.

Answer (score 1):

So basically, you have to study here the lattice of ideals of the product of rings. The facts go as follows:

The ideals of $\prod R_i$ are of the form $\prod \alpha_i$ where $\alpha_i$ is an ideal of $R_i$.

The primes ideals of $\prod R_i$ are the ideals $R_1 \times \ldots \times R_{i-1} \times \alpha_i \times R_{i+1} \times R_n$ where $\alpha_i$ is a prime ideal of $R_i$ (the same works for maximal ideals).

A ring $R$ is a field $\iff$ the only ideals are the trivial ones. That is $\{0\}$ and $R$ itself.

Then, $Spec(\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}) = (Spec(\mathbb{Q}) \times \mathbb{Q}) \cup (\mathbb{Q} \times Spec(\mathbb{Q}))$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field its only ideals are $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore the prime ones are $\{0\} \times \mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Q} \times \{0\}$ there are two more ideals but these do not count as prime.